# Is Nesting Promises Bad Practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know my code has the correct logic, but everywhere I look I'm told not to use nested promises. Is this a use case for nested promises?

The logic is as follows:

- promise1 fails -> reverse promise1
- promise1 succeeds -> promise2/promise3 fails -> reverse promise1,
  promise2, promise 3
- promise1 succeeds -> promise2 & promise3 succeeds

  ```
  let data = null;
  promise1.then((response) => {
      data = response;
      return Promise.all([promise2(), proimse3()])
          .catch((error) => {
              //Reverse only promise2, promise3
              //Throw error to reverse promise1
          });
  }).then((id) => {
      something(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
      //Reverse only promise1
  });
  ```

Comment: This is somewhat opinionated, but there's nothing wrong with nesting promises. Like functions, you just have to be careful not to nest too greedily or too deep.

Comment: _"but everywhere I look I'm told not to use nested promises."_ Can you share links to the resources that you are referencing?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong places. [Nesting promises is fine where appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20nesting%20promises), and that `catch` inside the `then` definitely is appropriate.

Comment: Regarding that `data` variable though, see [How do I access previous promise results in a `.then()` chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572). (Hint: [Nesting could help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) here as well :-))